# XSLT to remove few nodes and get a given node with its child nodes

Tags: xslt, stylesheet

Input

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body><jsonObject>
<User>
<No>123</No>
<Id>1</Id>
<MailCode>43</MailCode>
<Number>998</Number>
</User>
</jsonObject></soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Expected Output

```
<User xmlns="http://sample.org">
<No>123</No>
<Id>1</Id>
<MailCode>43</MailCode>
<Number>998</Number>
</User>
```

Current XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns="http://sample.org">


<xsl:template match="jsonObject">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="User">
        <!--Define the namespace -->
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://sample.org">
            <!--apply to above selected node-->
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">

        </xsl:apply-templates></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the current output is,

```
<User xmlns="http://sample.org">
123
1
43
998
</User>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also is there any way to directly extract the content of `<User>` node instead of writing separate templates to remove nodes like `<jsonObject>`?

Comment: The output you claim is not the output obtained by running the code you have posted. -- Note that the XML you have posted does not have any `JsonObject` or `Request` elements - so your stylesheet does nothing except apply the built-in template rules.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have added the correct XSLT now..Basically for the output I only need the <User> node and its child elements with the new namespace applied.

Comment: Your new XSLT does not produce the claimed output either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output can be achieved by applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="User | User/*" >
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://sample.org">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```